# Query All Subscribers for SubKey based on email address in DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have email addresses in a Data Extension and am trying to query All Subscribers to pull in their Subscriber Key. I wrote my Query, it validates, ran the SQL and it returned no records. Not sure where I went wrong.

```
Select
a.SubscriberKey,
EmailAddress
from [_subscribers] a
join [NameofDEwhereEmailAddressesAreStored] de
on de.Email = a.EmailAddress
```

I then have a new DE to point the SQL query to put the information.

Comment: although the default `join` is `inner join`, I would recommend explicitly stating it. Also, I would put an alias on `EmailAddress` in the Select statement (`a.EmailAddress`) to again remove ambiguity and reduce risk of misinterpretation. Outside of that, I would verify if you are in a child account or the parent account. If in a child account, you should use the prefix `ent.` on the Data View. So it would be `from ENT.[_subscribers] a`.  This tells the query to look at the enterprise level (parent) for the data view. This is where the all subscribers list lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Moving from Comment to Answer for better visibility:**

To start with, I would clean up your query a bit to ensure it is not something with a misinterpretation of ambiguity. Although the default join is inner join, I would recommend explicitly stating it to ensure understanding of your intention as well as to make it an easy reference when reviewing the code. Also, I would put an alias on EmailAddress in the Select statement (`a.EmailAddress`) to again remove ambiguity and reduce risk of misinterpretation.

Outside of that, I would verify if you are in a child account or the parent account. Because if you are in a child account, you should use the prefix `ENT.` on the _Subscribers Data View. Making it become `from ENT.[_subscribers] a`.

This tells the query to look at the enterprise level (parent) for the data view, which is where the 'All Subscribers' list lives.